# Rolling the data in R at customer id and product level

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, summary

I have the data on the format:-

```
id     product   mcg      txn
101    gold      hotel    1
101     gold      hotel   2
101     clas      hotel   22
101     clas       airline 23
```

I want the output as

```
           hotel_txn    airline_txn
101 gold   3              .
101 clas   22             23
```

can anyone pls help in getting me the desired output?

Basically I am searching for an alternative to Case when statement in SAS?

Comment: Try `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df1), id+product ~mcg, value.var="txn", sum)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `xtabs`

```
 xtabs(txn~idprod + mcg, transform(df1, idprod = paste(id, product),
              mcg = paste0(mcg, "_txn")))
 #         mcg
 #idprod     airline_txn hotel_txn
 # 101 clas          23        22
 # 101 gold           0         3
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshape2's dcast function is designed for this kind of stuff:

```
#creates your data frame
df <- data.frame(id = c(101, 101, 101, 101),
                 product = c("gold", "gold", "clas", "clas"),
                 mcg = c("hotel", "hotel", "hotel", "airline"),
                 txn = c(1, 2, 22, 23))

#installs and loads the required package
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)

#the function you would use to create the new data frame
df2 <- dcast(df, id + product ~ mcg, value.var = "txn", sum)

print(df2)
   id product airline hotel
1 101    clas      23    22
2 101    gold       0     3
```

Comment: id  product  airline  hotel  gold  class
1 101    clas      23    22     3        45   CAn we get the data in this form?

Comment: @ankitagarwal can you please clarify your request? I do not understand what you are asking for in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(id, product, mcg) %>% summarise(txn = sum(txn)) %>% spread(mcg, txn)
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: id, product [2]

     id product airline hotel
  <int>  <fctr>   <int> <int>
1   101    clas      23    22
2   101    gold      NA     3
```

Comment: Is gives the error that MCG column does not exist.can you pls help?